# In JDeveloper, How can I overwrite a webservice's address endpoint when generated from an EJB?

Tags: web-services, jdeveloper

I'm using JDeveloper (10.1.3.5) to create a web-service from an existing EJB.

Everytime I add a new method to the EJB and regenerate the webservice, the generated WSDL in    **{myproject}\src\META-INF\**     always has the endpoint address predefined to a fixed hostname and port.

Where can I change these settings in the project configuration (or variables)?

Comment: Why would you need that? Any generated client will be able to specified a different end point any way? :-/

Comment: I have to deploy them on several different QA environments (with different endpoints) and the client could also be an ESB.
So, I don’t enjoy going to each QA console to change the endpoint manually.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it may be possible using just JDeveloper, but if you integrate a project management tool like (Maven or Ivy), you should be able to do introduce a plugin or script that update the file during the build and accommodate the value using properties or build profiles.